# Can not set padding programatically to circular side in RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button, android-view, material-components-android, android-radiobutton

Im creating RadioButton with RTL layout so that the circle drawable will be on the right side. I need to create it programatically because it needs to dynamically added. But i found a problem when trying to give padding on the side in which the circle drawable exist. Whereas this is no problem when creating via xml.

I have tried giving padding while insantiating it like this:

```
val radioButton = MaterialRadioButton(context).apply {
    id = data.first
    text = data.second
    layoutDirection = LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    )
    setPadding(0,0, 100,0)
}
```

Or after it being added to the view.

```
binding.radioSelection.addView(radioButton)
binding.radioSelection.findViewById<RadioButton>(data.first).updatePadding(
    right = 100,
)
```

both no luck.

But if i create it using xml it will work. Either using paddingRight in xml or using this:

```
binding.dummyRadioButton3.updatePadding(
    right = 100,
)
```

Is it possible things to do or Google just blocked us from doing it?